# select a day from a period - reccurrence

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to implement a recurrence pattern for my Calendar Application. 
I want it to work the same way Outlook does when you set an appointment with reccurrence.

```
public async Task<ValidationResponse<ReccurrenceModel>> ApplyReccurrencePeriod (string userName, ReccurrenceModel value)
        {
            var user = await repository.FindByUserName(userName);

            var fromDateUTC = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value.FromDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            var toDateUTC = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value.ToDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);

            var dates = new List<DateTime>();
            var weeklyReccurrence = value.weeklyReccurrence;

            if (value.IsMonday == true)
            {
                var fromDate = value.FromDate;
                var toDate = value.ToDate;
                for (var dt = fromDate; dt < toDate; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
                {
                    dates.Add(dt);
                }
                var savedDates = dates.Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday).Select(x => x.Date);
            }
// I do the same code to verify every week day 

                var test = dates.Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday).Select(x => x.Date);
            }

            foreach (var date in savedDates) {
                var x = user.Holidays.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == date
                                     && kvp.Value.StateVal == value.State.StateVal);

                var dateUTC = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);

                user.Holidays[dateUTC] = value.State;

            }
            // save
            var updatedUser = await repository.UpdateEmployee(user);
            return await Task.FromResult(new ValidationResponse<HolidayModel>()
            {
                IsValid = true,
                Result = updatedUser.Holidays.ContainsKey(dateUTC) ? new HolidayModel() { Date = dateUTC, State = updatedUser.Holidays[dateUTC] } : null
            });

        }
    }
```

The problem with my code is that it works only if I have weekly reccurrence. I need to make it work in order to have 2, 3, ... n weeks reccurrence.
How can I make it skip some weeks?

```
 public class ReccurrenceModel
    {
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
        public int WeeklyReccurrence { get; set; }
        public State State { get; set; }
        public bool IsMonday { get; set; }
        public bool IsTuesday { get; set; }
        public bool IsWednesday { get; set; }
        public bool IsThursday { get; set; }
        public bool  IsFriday { get; set; }
        public DateTime FromDateToReturn { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToDateToReturn { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here ? How exactly should recurrence pattern work here ?

Comment: Please define the issues you are having.  What happens if you set it to 2, 3 .. n weeks

Comment: I want a list with every monday and friday between 01.05.2018 and 01.12.2018, but not weekly, every 3 weeks, let's say for example.

Comment: My code returns those days from every week and I want to skip some weeks using weeklyReccurrence variable

Comment: What is the type of `weeklyReccurrence` ? Please add code for `ReccurrenceModel` as well

Comment: @Fabjan, i did right now, sorry for that. It's an int :D

Comment: Try using my [implementation](https://github.com/atykhyy/RFC2445Recur/) of RFC 2445 recurrences. The rule you specified above would be expressed as two recurrences: `FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO;INTERVAL=3;UNTIL=2018-12-01` and one for Friday. As far as I understand RFC 2445 (and RFC 5545) do not allow to express this (two weekdays every three weeks) as one recurrence rule, but it has the advantage of being a standard.

Comment: I believe this question belong to CodeReview rather than StackOverflow, please, head there and post your question there so you get a better response, there are some issues in this code that can be addressed with a review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is a bit convoluted, there are a lot of lines that do nothing at all.

Here I provide a sample of code that, albeit not elegant at all, provides you with the behaviour you need, the following code will create a list of days that are recurrent every 2, 3, whatever you need weeks you define in its call.

This method also accepts a list of DayOfWeek for which you want the recurrence to be created

```
private static void GetRecurrentDays(DateTime fromDate, DateTime untilDate, uint weeklyRecurrence, List<DayOfWeek> recurrenceDays)
{
    var recurrenceDates = new List<DateTime>();
    for (var dt = fromDate; dt < untilDate; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (recurrenceDays.Any(day => day.Equals(dt.DayOfWeek)))
        {
            var lastDate = 
                recurrenceDates
                    .LastOrDefault(date => date.DayOfWeek.Equals(dt.DayOfWeek));

            // We multiply 7 days (a week) with weeklyRecurrence to 
            // calculate the appropiate date in which to add another day, 
            // calling with either 0 or 1 will calculate a weekly 
            // schedule
            if (lastDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) 
                || weeklyRecurrence.Equals(0)
                || ((dt - lastDate).Days % (7 * weeklyRecurrence)).Equals(0) )
            {
                recurrenceDates.Add(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can embed this code in yours in order to obtain the days with weekly recurrence and then, consume them further in your code